# htaccess redirect 301 with forward slash in parameters won't work

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I have done some research so far, but could not find the solution. I have a client who has this old file structure on the URL:

```
/index.php?process=views/article.php&articleId=44102
```

which should redirect to this URL:

```
/news/title-of-article/
```

I found that I may need this in my htacces file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &articleId=44102 [NC]
RewriteRule .* /news/title-of-article/ [R=301,L]
```

and when I test it with the full URL, it won't redirect. But when I leave out the forward slash like this:

```
/index.php?process=viewsarticle.php&articleId=44102
```

it redirects fine. So I assume the forward slash is the problem here.

I'm not a specialist in setting up .htaccess files and this drives me crazy, because it seems that I have the right solution in plain sight, but don't know why the forward slash is preventing the redirect.

If you can't answer with the final solution, I'd appreciate to have some kind of tool (website, software, etc) where I would be able to test these rewrite conditions in detail. Maybe there is something like the regex-testers that are available for regular expressions, but just for RewriteCond and RewriteRules that I can use to figure it out myself.

Thanks in advance
Marian

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're not stripping out QUERY_STRING In rewritten URI and because of that resulting URL also contains `QUERY_STRING` as `process=views/article.php&articleId=44102` and it matches rule again causing redirection loop.

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &articleId=44102 [NC]
RewriteRule .* /news/title-of-article/? [R=301,L]
```

`?` in the end will strip out existing query string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. unfortunately it is not solving the problem. it's still not redirecting the original URL but the URL without the forward slash redirects fine.

Comment: Use a different browser to test due to 301 caching issues.

Comment: I checked in a different browser. Same result. It must be related to the forward slash in the query_string.

Comment: Are you entering: `http://domain.com/index.php?process=views/article.php&articleId=44102` in your browser?

Comment: I think I found it. I had to place the rewrite conditions before the WordPress rewrite conditions. So it's now solved. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yes of course it must be before WP beast rule which grabs everything :P Didn't know you were using WP otherwise would have mentioned in my answer itself.